# $\mu$ measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

A set $A\subseteq X$ is $\textbf{$\mu-$measurable }$ if $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap A)+\mu(E\backslash A)$ for every $E\subseteq X$.

Note:
$\mu$ is an outer measure.

Problem:

The collection $M_\mu(X)$ of $\mu$-measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

My attempt:

Clearly, $\varnothing$ is $\mu$-measurable. Let $E\subseteq X$ be arbitrary. Then $\mu(E\cap X)+\mu(E\backslash X)=\mu(E)$. Hence $X$ is $\mu$-measurable.

Suppose $A$ is $\mu$-measurable. I must show that $X\backslash A$ is likewise $\mu$-measurable. Let $E\subseteq X$, then $\mu(E\cap X\backslash A)$ $+$ $\mu(E\cap A)$. Since $A$ is $\mu$-measurable, it follows that $\mu(E\cap A)=\mu(E)- \mu(E\cap X\backslash A)$ and so $\mu(E\cap X\backslash A) + \mu(E\cap A)=\mu(E)$. Hence $X\backslash A$ is likewise $\mu$-measurable.

How do I show the last condition? May I have hints? Note: I just started learning measure theory.

Comment: See [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2014h/caratheodory.pdf). The idea is first to prove that the union of two disjoint $\mu$-measurable sets is again measurable. Then for an arbitrary countable union of sets, one can define a new set of sets which is pairwise disjoint, and use induction from the first part. I.e. if $A=\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n$, then define $B_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_k$, $B_0=\emptyset$ and $C_n=B_n \setminus B_{n-1}$, so that $A=\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}C_n$, where this union is disjoint.